# Compare only time part in datetime - Python

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.x

I want to compare only time part in datetime. I have different dates with only time field to compare. Since dates are different and only time part i want to consider So i think creating two datetime object will not help.
my string as

```
start="22:00:00"
End="03:00:00"
Tocompare="23:30:00"
```

Above are strings when i convert them with datetime as

```
dt=datetime.strptime(start,"%H:%M:%S")
```

it gives

```
1900-01-01 22:00:00
```

which is default date in python.
So i need to avoid all this and want only time part. I simply need to check does my `Tocompare` falls between `start` and `End`

Answer (score 59):

Just call the `.time()` *method* of the `datetime` objects to get their hours, minutes, seconds and microseconds.

```
dt = datetime.strptime(start,"%H:%M:%S").time()
```

Answer (score 10):

Compare their times using [datetime.time()](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.time).

Comment: even time module considers date part and i need only time part.@jarmod

Comment: According to http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time, a time object represents a (local) time of day, independent of any particular day.

Answer (score 2):

```
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, '%H:%M:%S')
start = datetime.time(start.hour, start.minute,start.second)

tocompare = datetime.datetime.strptime(tocompare, '%H:%M:%S')
tocompare = datetime.time(tocompare.hour, tocompare.minute, tocompare.second)

start > tocompare # False
```