# How do I get rid of the year, month, and day?

Tags: python, datetime

I was trying to write a program that converts a string to datetime type. The code looks like this.

```
import datetime
time="20:36"
p=datetime.datetime.strptime(time, "%H:%M")
print(p)
```

and the output was

```
1900-01-01 20:36:00
```

How do I get rid of the '1990-01-01' ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare only time part in datetime - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105112/compare-only-time-part-in-datetime-python)

Comment: There is always a lot of support for formatting date outputs. [Here are a lot of things you can do](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

Comment: `p.time()` will return a `time` object that only has the time, discarding the default date added to the `datetime` object by `datetime.strptime`. (This wouldn't be necessary if `time` itself had a `strptime` method, but alas.)

Answer (score 1):

It's unfortunate that you cannot simply write

```
p = datetime.time.strptime(time, "%H:%M")
```

because `time.strptime` is not defined. You are forced to use `datetime.strptime`, which returns a `datetime` object no matter what fields are actually being parsed.

On the plus side, you can get the `time` object you want relatively easily.

```
t = p.time()
print(t)  # Outputs 20:36:00
```

Comment: Yes it is unfortunate. Maybe developers will see your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a `datetime` object from your string and displaying the `datetime` as a whole.

### What you should do:

display just the time part:

1. use `strftime`:

The code

```
import datetime
time="20:36"
p=datetime.datetime.strptime(time, "%H:%M")
print(p.strftime("%H:%M"))
```

2. use `time`:

The code:

```
import datetime
time="20:36"
p=datetime.datetime.strptime(time, "%H:%M")
print(p.time())
```

### What you really should do:

Create a `time` object from your data. For that you can use `datetime.time`

```
import datetime
time="20:36"
hour, minute = time.split(":")

t = datetime.time(hour=int(hour), minute=int(minute))
print(t)
```

Comment: I would prefer #2 to manually parsing the time string to get the arguments for `datetime.time`.